# How to pass the json_query value into Ansible playbook parameter?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook (as shown below) which contains 2 tasks: create folders, and copy a file into one of the created folder.

```
- hosts: test2
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: create folders
      file:
        path: "{{ item.folderName }}"
        state: directory
      with_items:
        - { folderName: /root/testFolder }
        - { folderName: /root/testFolder2 }
      register: fd

    - name: copy file to folder
      copy:
        src: /root/t1.txt
        dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query("[?item.folderName==`/root/testFolder`].path") }}"
        remote_src: true
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'
      register: fl
```

In the second task where I want to copy a file to one of the created folder (/root/testFolder), I have difficulty in passing value to the `dest` parameter. Because I want to use json_query to get the return path value from first task, and pass it to this `dest` parameter. However, when I run this playbook, I got an error message:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/ansible/test/createFolder.yaml': line 25, column 44, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        src: /root/t1.txt
        dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query("[?item.folderName==`/root/testFolder`].path") }}"
                                           ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

The expected output from the first task is like this:

```
ok: [xxx.xxx] => {
    "fd": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "diff": {
                    "after": {
                        "path": "/root/testFolder",
                        "state": "directory"
                    },
                    "before": {
                        "path": "/root/testFolder",
                        "state": "absent"
                    }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "gid": 0,
                "group": "root",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_diff_peek": null,
                        "_original_basename": null,
                        "access_time": null,
                        "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "attributes": null,
                        "follow": true,
                        "force": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "modification_time": null,
                        "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "owner": null,
                        "path": "/root/testFolder",
                        "recurse": false,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "state": "directory",
                        "unsafe_writes": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "folderName": "/root/testFolder"
                },
                "mode": "0755",
                "owner": "root",
                "path": "/root/testFolder",
                "size": 4096,
                "state": "directory",
                "uid": 0
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "diff": {
                    "after": {
                        "path": "/root/testFolder2",
                        "state": "directory"
                    },
                    "before": {
                        "path": "/root/testFolder2",
                        "state": "absent"
                    }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "gid": 0,
                "group": "root",
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_diff_peek": null,
                        "_original_basename": null,
                        "access_time": null,
                        "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "attributes": null,
                        "follow": true,
                        "force": false,
                        "group": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "modification_time": null,
                        "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
                        "owner": null,
                        "path": "/root/testFolder2",
                        "recurse": false,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "state": "directory",
                        "unsafe_writes": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "folderName": "/root/testFolder2"
                },
                "mode": "0755",
                "owner": "root",
                "path": "/root/testFolder2",
                "size": 4096,
                "state": "directory",
                "uid": 0
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

Then I modified the playbook by changing `dest` value into `"{{ fd.results[0].path }}"`, and print the json_query in debug as follows:

```
- hosts: test2
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: create folders
      file:
        path: "{{ item.folderName }}"
        state: directory
      with_items:
        - { folderName: /root/testFolder }
        - { folderName: /root/testFolder2 }
      register: fd
    - debug:
        var: fd.results | json_query("[?item.folderName==`/root/testFolder`].path")

    - name: copy file to folder
      copy:
        src: /root/t1.txt
        dest: "{{ fd.results[0].path }}"
        remote_src: true
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'
      register: fl
```

I can run the playbook successfully, and can get the json_query result in debug:

```
ok: [xxx.xxx] => {
    "fd.results | json_query(\"[?item.folderName==`/root/testFolder`].path\")": [
        "/root/testFolder"
    ]
}
```

Although I can fix the original playbook by using this `dest: "{{ fd.results[0].path }}"`,but I just want to know how fix the syntax error on the original second task when passing the json_query value to `dest`. Because I can print out the json_query result using debug in the second modified playbook, but just don't know how to pass it to `dest` param. Like if I use `dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query("[?item.folderName==`/root/testFolder`].path") }}"`,it will give me an error as shown above.

Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***I just want to know how fix the syntax error on the original second task when passing the `json_query` value to `dest`.***

Use single quotes for your query `` json_query('[?item.folderName==`./test/testFolder1`].path') `` instead of double quotes.

> ***I can print out the `json_query` result using `debug` in the second modified playbook, but just don't know how to pass it to `dest` param.***

The result will be a list with one element only, whereby the copy module `dest` expect a string, not a list. Therefore use the first (single) element `` dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query('[?item.folderName==`./test/testFolder1`].path') | first }}" ``.

---

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Make sure folders are created
    file:
      path: "{{ item.folderName }}"
      state: directory
    with_items:
      - { folderName: ./test/testFolder1 }
      - { folderName: ./test/testFolder2 }
    register: fd

  - debug:
      var: fd.results | json_query('[?item.folderName==`./test/testFolder1`].path')

  - name: Make sure the file is in the folder
    copy:
      src: test.file
      dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query('[?item.folderName==`./test/testFolder1`].path') | first }}"
    register: fl
```

will result into the Desired State Configuration. Despite of that it is recommend to simplify the tasks a lot. You may have a look into the following minimal example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    FOLDER_LIST:
      - testFolder1
      - testFolder2

  tasks:

  - name: Make sure folders are created
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: directory
    loop: "{{ FOLDER_LIST }}"

  - name: Make sure the file is in the folder
    copy:
      src: test.file
      dest: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
      - "{{ FOLDER_LIST | first }}"
```

Comment: I tried to use vars_file to read this folderName. Like in a var file (yaml), I put 'folderName: /home/ubuntu/testFolder'. However, when I used this dest: "{{ fd.results | json_query('[?item.folderName == `{{ folderName}}`].path') | first }}" in the playbook, I got an error saying 'empty list, can't get the first element'. Do you knwo what is the reason for it?